# Add NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers for only some specific commands

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Are there any risks for letting the beyond password to be used with no password?

It is a home computer, with no other users using it, I only use the single default created user when Ubuntu was installed.

I would like to don't have to write at all the sudo password for these commands:

```
echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full

dhclient eth0

apt-get update && upgrade && dist-upgrade -y

apt-get autoremove && remove && clean && autoclean -y
```

Thank you.

ANSWER:
It seams that these steps resolved this case:

```
sudo su
```

Create `/usr/local/bin/scriptname` and write the beyond lines in it:

```
#!/bin/bash

command in here without sudo

# the end of the script's name
```

_

```
Create /etc/sudoers.d/scriptname and write the following lines in it:

User_Alias scriptname=username
Cmnd_Alias scriptabreviaton=/home/globalisation/r
scriptname ALL=NOPASSWD: scriptabreviaton
```

Add at the end of `/etc/sudoers` the next two lines:

```
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/scriptname
```

_

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/scriptname
chown root:root /usr/local/bin/scriptname
chmod 0700 /usr/local/bin/scriptname
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/scriptname
```

_

From the regular user name:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/scriptname
```

It shouldn't ask for sudo password any more.

Everywhere when it is written "scriptname", "usernme", "scriptabreviaton" every each of them should be the same.

Comment: Please don't cross post https://askubuntu.com/q/923170/72216 you already got an answer there.

Answer (score 8):

If you only need these exact commands you could create a script for each case under `/usr/local/sbin` and add those scripts into your sudoers file like:

```
you ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
you ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/backlight.sh
you ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/upgrade.sh
```

Don't forget to `chown` your scripts to root and also remove all unnecessary modes via `chmod`:

```
chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/backlight.sh
chmod go-rwx /usr/local/sbin/backlight.sh
```

Comment: I appreciate @Gábor Héja I am not so advanced and I have never used or made any script until now, can you please share a link where I can find out more please? And if you have some specific tips and tricks about add in the script those specific commands I am looking for please, indeed, I am looking just for only "these exact commands". Regards.

Comment: Of course. It's actually pretty easy, start a text editor (as root as you're trying to save to /usr/local/sbin) place `#!/bin/bash` as the frist line, then an empty line, then your commands. Save it to the correct place, do the `chown` and `chmod` as in the earlier example and you're done. And a note, never edit the **/etc/sudoers** directly, always by running `visudo`. You can render your system unusable otherwise (due to even a simple typo).

Comment: I appreciate @GáborHéja. Unfortunately it doesn't work, I've been very careful and check for many times everything to be in order, like you suggested, and none of the commands work without asking for the sudo password. Have you tried something like that yourself, and it worked? Could it influence in any way the fact that I use Lubuntu minimal installation ? Thank you.

Comment: When i issue `chmod` as you described I got `Permission denied`

Comment: @SalemF, try to run as root or `sudo chmod [...]`

Comment: no I mean after I `chmod` with `root` account I can run it with `user` account I had to change it back with `chmod +x` and `chmod +r`

Comment: Then either the sudoers is not loading the file (try to move the lines directly to `/etc/sudoers`) or you're missing the `sudo` before the script, i.e. `sudo /usr/local/sbin/backlight.sh` or the script is trying to do something weird.