# I need an example of this

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, gui

I have a problem using win-kex basic mode for Kali on WSL2, it has a connection fail. I can solve it running this command before launch: `sudo mount -o remount rw /tmp/.X11-unix`
(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577819/how-to-fix-the-error-error-connecting-to-the-kex-server)

I want to write a NOPASSWD line on sudoers just for avoid the password request everytime just for this command. So, searching info I found this post: [Add NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers for only some specific commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369852/add-nopasswd-in-etc-sudoers-for-only-some-specific-commands).
The person who asked, edited the post and shared an answer, but when I tried to use it, visudo "explodes" the screen with a lot of errors (syntax errors, mostly) and is just because of I don't understand very well all about User_Alias, Cmnd_Alias, and others sudoers configurations.

The issue is in the sudoers.d file, so I would like an example about that point for use it as guideline.

**Edit:**

I already created the "win_kex" file as root on `/usr/local/bin/` with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -o remount rw /tmp/.X11-unix
#
```

And I created another file "winkex" on `sudoers.d` following the steps on the post shared before: (myusername=kapichy97)

```
User_Alias winkex=myusername
Cmnd_Alias WK=/home/globalisation/r
winkex ALL=NOPASSWD WK
```

Then added the lines on sudoers:

```
myusername ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myusername ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/winkex
```

And just save, exit and visudo show several errors.[image]

Comment: `sudoers.d` is NOT a file, it's a directory

Comment: Yeah, I mean the file in that location. I create a file named winkex

Comment: Can you add **to the question** the following. 1: the content of the file you're trying to edit, and 2: the command (exactly) you run, 3: the file owner and permissions of the file you are editing

Comment: hmmm - odd that the the errors suggest the file has completely different content

Comment: Exactly, It's obvious, I didn´t understand the post, that's why I would like an example, to use it as a guide.

Comment: so, you create a file called `winkex` and `visudo` complains about a file called `win_kex`?? that is odd - perhaps you should check what files exist in `sudoers.d`

Comment: as for examples, a search for `example sudoers file` yields many useful results

Comment: Well. I was following the steps on this edited post, because I use it the answers methods but didn't work. So, I was trying using the edited info on this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369852/add-nopasswd-in-etc-sudoers-for-only-some-specific-commands

What do you advise me for make that NOPASSWD for that command?

Comment: @JaromandaX Formally (POSIX-ly) every directory is a [file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_164), a file of the type directory. A directory is not a regular file.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski what is the relevance of your comment to the OP's problem?

Comment: Well, right now I understand the @JaromandaX comment, I just tried making a simple script and make a direct NOPASSWD to this file, named "win_kex.sh". I had to change that didn't have "remount,rw" but "remount,rm" but for some bash didn´t show me nothing. But now could solve it. Thank you for you help.

Comment: @JaromandaX You have "corrected" the OP, blatantly said "`sudoers.d` is NOT a file". Well, it is a file. You could "correct" the OP, so I could correct you. IMO it's good for the OP (or anyone working with Linux) to learn the POSIX terminology.

Comment: Consider updating the question's title so that a reader can see what the question is actually about without having to read all text.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - you're right, pedantry helps the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JaromandaX said on comments, there's no need to make all that stuff that I found on the shared post. Just ensure that the command is right, obviously run `chmod -x` and check the sudoers file. So, the steps are this:

1. Create a script with sh extension on any path (mine was `win_kex.sh` on `/usr/local/bin`)
2. Make executable the script using `chmod -x` (`chmod -x /usr/local/bin/win_kex.sh`)
3. Edit sudoers file using `sudo visudo` adding the NOPASSWD rule as the last line of file: `myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Path/to/the/file` (kapichy97 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/win_kex.sh).

And that's all.